# How to integrate nodebb in iframe in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, iframe, nodebb

I am trying to integrate the nodebb in my react app but its not loading in the iframe. Its giving error like refused to connect .

Refused to display 'http://192.241.158.178:4567/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Answer (score 0):

I got it just need to give the domain where it will be access in iframe. 
git to Admindashboard>setting>advance> set the domain name.